# Requested link does not open in selenium chromedriver:

Tags: selenium

This is a new post I made after feedback from some members:

Here is the code I have:

```
from selenium import webdriver

#Create a path 
PATH = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r'C:\Users\sanas\Downloads\chromedriver_win32\chromedriver.exe')

#Create a driver 
driver = webdriver.Chrome(PATH)

#Open a website:
driver.get("https://www.google.com")
```

The problem is it apparently does load chrome browser but not the exact link I want.

[Chrome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7FLEr.png)

Additionally, I want to know if my path for chrome driver is okay

(C:\Users\sanas\Downloads\chromedriver_win32)

[Path for chromedriver](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dntWi.png)

Comment: _new post I made after feedback from some members_: Seems you have completely [**deleted the helpful post**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/71950419/7429447) altogether along with the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71950683/7429447)

Answer (score 0):

maybe your "PATH" is wrong.it should be a str.
PATH = r'C:\Users\sanas\Downloads\chromedriver_win32\chromedriver.exe'

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).